# Is it possible to have many select tags in one html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to create a form that has two different dropdown lists to select from,(for example a dropdown list to select a name and a dropdown list to select age). Then i want to print them under the form . Then i must be able to select again other options and they will be printed after the fist option's print.

Is this possible?

```
 <form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <select id="name">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                
        </select>
        <select id="age">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and how i can pass the selected value to php?

Comment: 1. Yes it's possible. 2. You need to give your `<select>` elements a name and add an action to  `<form ...>`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is  $variable = $_POST['name'];  where name is <select name="name"> the way to access the option in the php code?

Comment: Yes when you use `method="post"` it's `$_POST[...]` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    <form id='form'>
        <select id='name' name='selectName'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
        </select>
        <select id='age' name='selectAge'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
    <div id='print'></div> <!-- Here you will print the submitted values -->
</body>
</html>

<!-- ES6 syntax -->
<script>

    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const print = document.getElementById('print');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload

        const name = this.querySelector('#name').value; // get the name
        const age = this.querySelector('#age').value; // get the age

        print.innerHTML += `<div>Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}</div>`; // print name and age below the form

        // here you can perform an AJAX call to your PHP file and do something with it

    });

</script>
```

In this case there is no reason to put `action='YOUR_PHP_FILE.php'` in the form, because you want to keep the page and the printed messages below, so just perform AJAX call behind the scenes. Normally you would do:

```
<form id='form' action='YOUR_PHP_FILE.php' method='POST'>
    // ...
</form>
```

In the `php` file you can do something like:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['selectName'];
    $age = $_POST['selectAge'];

    // do something with these values ...

?>
```

Here is old Javascript version:

```
<!-- Old syntax -->
<script>

    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var print = document.getElementById('print');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload

        var name = this.querySelector('#name').value; // get the name
        var age = this.querySelector('#age').value; // get the age

        print.innerHTML += '<div>Name: ' + name + ', Age: ' + age + '</div>'; // print name and age below the form

        // here you can perform an AJAX call to your PHP file and something with it

    });

</script>
```